# integer to string with leading zeros

Tags: postscript

Good afternoon,

I'm very new to postscript and looking into coding graphic elements for XMPie applications for post-composition integration.

Something I'm having trouble wrapping my head around is converting an integer to a 3-digit padded string.

IE 1 -> "001", 20 -> "020", 400 -> "400"

Any push in the right direction is very appreciated.

Comment: What code do you have so far and what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/padthree
{
  1000 add 7 string cvs 1 3 getinterval
} def

1 padthree
```

eg:

```
/padthree
{
  1000 add 7 string cvs 1 3 getinterval
} def
1 padthree
5 padthree
40 padthree
stack
```

outputs

```
040
005
001
PS<SSS>
```

Comment: I appreciate the help but your snippet is javascript, not postscript

Comment: did this solve your problem?  consider accepting this answer as your solution